# tinyMCE alert what you just wrote

Tags: tinymce

In the tinyMCE init editor,

How can i in setup do:

```
      ed.onKeyDown.add(function (ed, evt) {
         // alert the character you just typed
      });
```

Say if you type "a" a alert should come up with "a"

Answer (score 1):

The `evt.keyCode` property contains the code of the pressed key, so you can do this:

```
alert(String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode));
```

Note, however, that this will also trigger an alert when a special key is pressed (e.g. shift), so you might want to prevent that by checking other properties of the `evt` object (which is an instance of DOM Event). See the documentation for keyboard event objects at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/KeyboardEvent.

**Edit:** Use `onKeyPress` instead of `onKeyDown`, as `onKeyDown` might return incorrect key codes in some browsers.

Comment: So i should check that its not a shift, f1, f2 etc. etc. ?

Comment: Yes, you basically need to check if the key code is in the printable characters range.